# Maven multi-modules with different versions in the same Git repository

Tags: git, maven

I need an advice regarding constructing my maven modules. Here is my setup:

I currently have a single module that contains a lot of code which I would like to break into multiple submodules. The thing is that I would like each of those new modules to have its own version and hopefully to have them all share the same parent-pom.

Main main concern is whether I put each module in its own Git repository (for instance: Bitbucket repo), or I could, ideally, have them all under the same Bitbucket repo??

Advantages/disadvantages in terms of maintenance, building, releasing ...any input could really help!

Thanks.

Comment: Why should each of them has it's own version? I suppose you will release them all at the same time or together in one go as up to now... ?

Comment: Each of these modules is independent of the others thus has its own version, If you find a bug in one of these modules you only interested to fix the bug and release this module which would increment its version so you can put this version in the project that uses it.

Comment: But at the moment you have one module and release / deploy at a particular time. Because you wrote single module... So why changing that ... and making it harder to maintain ? separating the modules is good based on architectural things etc. Also those you consume it need to upgrade each version of each part artifact separately...

Comment: The plan is to go to multimodules with independent version for each module. The big question for me is whether to host every module in its own repo or all of them in the same repo - I'm trying to wrap my head around release & deploy process in case need to release only one module and not all of them (which would cause bump up version to all modules).

Comment: Are those "modules" independent from each other ? I repeat my question: Why do you like to separate something which has been combined before..why really changing that? Where do you see the advantage? I've already mentioned disadv. I would go with a multi module build and that's it... single release setup etc. Easier for consumers to understand ...apart from that you have to test a lot of different version combinations with each other?

Comment: Each submodule represents a major feature. We have 3 products and each can use different features. so we would like to make the product pom depend on those submodules (features) each with its own version.
The features are independent one from the other so there is no need to make tests between them. If feature get bug fix it might interest only one product but not the other, so a product can decide what version it depends on in its own pom.

Comment: That sounds like you should go creating separate git repos for those "features" ... so one feature (module) is for different "products"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240538/discussion-between-shvalb-and-khmarbaise).